# what is the shortcut key to Swap Presenter View and Slide show view while presenting in powerpoint 2016?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2016

what is the shortcut key to Swap Presenter View and Slide show view while presenting in PowerPoint 2016?
the item is visible in the picture but I need a shortcut key, I also couldn't find it in the list of customize ribbon commands to assign a hotkey to it manually.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there *is* a shortcut key for this, unfortunately, and unlike Excel and Word, PowerPoint doesn't allow us to assign hotkeys to ribbon commands. If any hotkey is already assigned, it should appear as a tooltip when you press and hold ALT (in Windows versions; Option, probably, on Mac).

Answer (score 0):

There is no shortcut for this,
but the easiest way would be to use <kbd>Windows key</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
and then **extend** your screen. 
When you start a presentation using <kbd>F5</kbd>,
PowerPoint should show the presenter view on the PC screen
and the slide show on the secondary screen (projector) by default.

Comment: Unfortunately, this behaviour is not guaranteed in PowerPoint yet. It sometimes show the presenter view on the secondary screen and needs manual swapping.